# Classification of users by purchase history

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-engineering

I am fairly new to machine learning and I am learning with a book.

So if I want to classify customers by their purchases, how would that look?

Age and sex would be single features, but what about the purchase history? 1 customer could have 10.000 or more purchases (each article is categorized: electronics, hardware, software, ...) some may only have 1000 or 100.

So my data should look like this

```
customerId | sex  | age | purchases 
-----------|------|-----|-----------
383848     |  w   | 35  | 1234, 49239
```

and not like this?

```
customerId | sex  | age | purchase1 | purchase2 | purchase3
-----------|------|-----|-----------|-----------|----------
383848     |  w   | 35  | 1234      | 49239     | null
```

The examples I have done until now don't cover this - so any pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: Neither choice of representing the data is a good one for most purposes.  For a better and principled approach, consult resources on data modeling and relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite number of purchase types (electronics, hardware, etc.), you could represent each category as a set of variables describing stuff like:

- Total number of purchases in the category
- Amount of money spent on this category
- Statistics like average price of items bought, maximum price of items bought, etc.
- Frequency of purchases
- ...generally whatever is possible to extract from your data (you did not give any details how this purchase records look like)

This whole process is called **feature engineering**. I would recommend first generating many such features and perhaps later remove uninformative ones using some **feature selection** techniques. The second step is not necessary with some classifiers which can learn ignoring uninformative features.

There is no general way how to perform feature engineering: It is an art in itself and every learning task might need different features.